# Ionic app Code signing “capacitor.framework” failed on Macbook M1

Tags: ionic-framework, apple-m1

I am unable to archive my app on Mac M1 machine.
There are a couple of apps that I published on apple store. On the new M1 machine I am able to build these ionic apps and deploy them on my phone using Xcode. However when I am trying to archive the apps both the apps are giving this error.

> Code signing “capacitor.framework” failed

[image: Error Image screenshot]

Comment: Did you read the second line in your picture? What happened then?

Comment: Well the distribution logs are quite lengthy which might not fit here. In summary it says the following:
Beginning distribution assistant for archive: App, task: 2
Proceeding to distribution step IDEDistributionDestinationStepViewController[...] distributionDestination(resolved)='(null)', distributionMethod(resolved)='<IDEDistributionMethodiOSAppStoreDistribution: 0x145817650>', team(resolved)='(null)'>
I thought the issue is with signing. I re-downloaded certs, profiles but this did not resolve the issue. Any guesses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also got this issue and fixed it by hit and trial method.

**The problem with me was that:**

On this screen the first option i.e. *Include bitcode for iOS content* was automatically checked. I unchecked it and the problem got resolved.

[See this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mQLd.png)

Here is [the link to my GitHub issue](https://github.com/ionic-team/capacitor/issues/4768) that I opened and closed myself. Silly me.

Comment: Yes. this resolved my issue too. Thanks to the solution given in this link:https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/code-signing-capacitor-framework-failed-on-macbook-m1/211077/2

Comment: Perfect, had same issue on my MacBook Pro running macOs 12 Beta.